# Restrict Postfix only for allowed Mail-Adresses

Tags: postfix

I want to restrict my postfix system. Exactly I will that my postfix allow to send mails only to allowed user, all other mails should be bounced.

For example:

This Mails should be send:

```
user1@example.com
user2@example.com
user3@example.com
```

All other Mails should not sended, for Example

```
user4@example.com
user5@example.com

etc.
```

I tried, the following settings, but it doesn't work:

```
 smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/valid_recipients
    reject_unlisted_sender 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject
```

Have you any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make use of either [local_recipient_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps) or [`relay_recipient_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_recipient_maps) depending on your situation.

For a single system you'll likely use `hash:`. For keeping multiple systems in sync, you should use `ldap:` or `mysql:`